# Image not loading in React project

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

So i'm working on a movie project and getting movie details from api call, for the img tag i combined base url and img path from api response, the images are not loading even though the url is correct. I checked the url by logging it in console and when i click on the img link from console i get redirected to a page displaying the movie img so i guess i made a mistake in img tag and not able to figure out what.
[This is what i get in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ezkag.jpg)
[When i logged the url in console i get proper urls and these redirect me to the image when i click them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50zsK.jpg)
[This is the code, mapping the movies array and displaying individual posters, appending "img_url" to "movie.poster_path" to get the full poster link.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqdfS.jpg)

I tried modifying the path for src attribute in img tag but nothing changes.

Comment: Can you please add code to show what you are doing?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Are there any console errors? Are there any failed requests in the Network tab (select Img as type)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in your code, attribute src should have `movie.poster_path`, not `movies.poster_path`